# Subsetting data.frame in in specific order in R (for setting vertex attributes)

Tags: r, networking, dataframe, subset, sna

I have information in a data.frame containing of two columns e.g.:

```
name  age
a     10
b     20
c     30
```

and I have a list of names `c b d`. Now I want to obtain a data.frame (or list or anything) of the attributes of the original data frame in the order of the list. For the above example, that would be

```
name  age
c     30
b     20
d     NA
```

I feel that this shouldn't be too difficult (even in-line maybe)  but I can't find a way to do it in R.

**Background:**

I have a 'network' object created from an edge list. I have another of vertex-attributes, but no power over how each of these is ordered initially. Now I want
assign the network vertices these attributes.

But in order to use

- `network %v% "age" <- dataframe[,2]` I'd need the data frame to be in the right order

and for

- `set.vertex.attribute(network, "age", hhs$age, v = hhs$di)` I'd need the vertex ids

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I took your list of names `ls` and made it a `data.frame` with the same `name` name.

I then used `left_join` from `dplyr`

```
ls<-c("c","b","d")
df2<-data.frame(name=ls)

df2 %>% left_join(df,by="name")->new_df

> new_df
  name age
1    c  30
2    b  20
3    d  NA
```

Or, if you're unfamiliar with the dplyr/magrittr piping, you could re-write this as:

```
new_df<-left_join(df2,df,by="name")
```

As it yields the same result:

```
> new_df
  name age
1    c  30
2    b  20
3    d  NA
```

In fact, since `df2` only has `name`, you don't even need to specify the `by=` argument.

```
new_df<-left_join(df2,df)
```

yields the same result.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in a single line in base R with the `match` function:

```
data.frame(name=names, age=df$age[match(names, df$name)])
#   name age
# 1    c  30
# 2    b  20
# 3    d  NA
```

Data:

```
names <- c("c", "b", "d")
df <- data.frame(name=c("a", "b", "c"), age=c(10, 20, 30))
```